# how to keep elasticsearch's indexes while updating from version 1.5 to 5.6.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, logstash

I have Elasticsearch 1.5 installed on my machine, I am planning to migrate to Elasticsearch 5.6.1, how can I make it without losing my indexes.

Answer (score 0):

From 1.x to 5.x you need to reindex to upgrade. You won't lose any of your data. Follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/reindex-upgrade.html) link